# Is there a way to add the ul label to the output?

Tags: php, zen-cart

```
<?php

  $content = "";

  $content .= '<div id="' . str_replace('_', '-', $box_id . 'Content') . '" class="sideBoxContent">' . "\n";
  for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($box_categories_array);$i++) {
    switch(true) {
// to make a specific category stand out define a new class in the stylesheet example: A.category-holiday
// uncomment the select below and set the cPath=3 to the cPath= your_categories_id
// many variations of this can be done
//      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['path'] == 'cPath=3'):
//        $new_style = 'category-holiday';
//        break;
      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['top'] == 'true'):
        $new_style = 'category-top';
        break;
      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']):
        $new_style = 'category-subs';
        break;
      default:
        $new_style = 'category-products';
      }
     if (zen_get_product_types_to_category($box_categories_array[$i]['path']) == 3 or ($box_categories_array[$i]['top'] != 'true' and SHOW_CATEGORIES_SUBCATEGORIES_ALWAYS != 1)) {
        // skip if this is for the document box (==3)
      } else {
      $content .= '<li class="' . $new_style . '"><a  href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $box_categories_array[$i]['path']) . '">';

      if ($box_categories_array[$i]['current']) {
        if ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']) {
          $content .= '<span class="category-subs-parent">' . $box_categories_array[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
        } else {
          $content .= '<span class="category-subs-selected">' . $box_categories_array[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
        }
      } else {
        $content .= $box_categories_array[$i]['name'];
      }

      if ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']) {
        $content .= CATEGORIES_SEPARATOR;
      }
      $content .= '</a></li>';

      if (SHOW_COUNTS == 'true') {
        if ((CATEGORIES_COUNT_ZERO == '1' and $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] == 0) or $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] >= 1) {
          $content .= CATEGORIES_COUNT_PREFIX . $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] . CATEGORIES_COUNT_SUFFIX;
        }
      }

      $content .=  "\n";
    }
  }
```

the above html output like this:
[image]

Now, I want to add some `ul` label into the output. Namely, when it's `category-top` and have sub category. I want to make the output like this.

```
<li class="category-top"> <a href="#">main category</a>
<ul>
<li class="category-topb"><a href="#">sub category</a></li>
<li class="category-topb"><a href="#">sub category</a></li>
<li class="category-topb"><a href="#">sub category</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

When it doesn't have sub category the output is like this  `<li class="category-top"> <a href="#">...</a></li>`.

How to add the ul label?
Thank you!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=1
            [name] => Hardware
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_17
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CDROM Drives
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_4
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Graphics Cards
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_8
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Keyboards
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_16
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Memory
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_9
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mice
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_6
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monitors
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_5
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Printers
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_7
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Speakers
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=2
            [name] => Software
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=2_19
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=2_18
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Simulation
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=2_20
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Strategy
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=3
            [name] => DVD Movies
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_10
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_13
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cartoons
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_12
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comedy
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_15
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Drama
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_11
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Science Fiction
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_14
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thriller
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=21
            [name] => Gift Certificates
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=22
            [name] => Big Linked
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=23
            [name] => Test Examples
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=24
            [name] => Free Call Stuff
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=33
            [name] => A Top Level Cat
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_34
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubLevel 2 A
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_34_40
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2A1
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_34_43
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2A2
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubLevel 2 B
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35_37
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2B1
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35_38
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2B2
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35_39
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2B3
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubLevel 2 C
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36_41
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2C1
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36_44
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2C2
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36_42
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2C3
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=48
            [name] => Sale Percentage
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_45
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_47
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off Attrib
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_31
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off Skip
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_32
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off Price
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=49
            [name] => Sale Deduction
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=49_27
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$5.00 off
        )
......
```

Comment: you got the solution of the this problem or not? i have same problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $content = "";

  $content .= '<div id="' . str_replace('_', '-', $box_id . 'Content') . '" class="sideBoxContent">' . "\n";
  for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($box_categories_array);$i++) {
    switch(true) {
// to make a specific category stand out define a new class in the stylesheet example: A.category-holiday
// uncomment the select below and set the cPath=3 to the cPath= your_categories_id
// many variations of this can be done
//      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['path'] == 'cPath=3'):
//        $new_style = 'category-holiday';
//        break;
      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['top'] == 'true'):
        $new_style = 'category-top';
        break;
      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']):
        $new_style = 'category-subs';
        break;
      default:
        $new_style = 'category-products';
      }
     if (zen_get_product_types_to_category($box_categories_array[$i]['path']) == 3 or ($box_categories_array[$i]['top'] != 'true' and SHOW_CATEGORIES_SUBCATEGORIES_ALWAYS != 1)) {
        // skip if this is for the document box (==3)
      } else {
      $content .= '<li class="' . $new_style . '"><a  href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $box_categories_array[$i]['path']) . '">';

      if ($box_categories_array[$i]['current']) {
        if ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']) {
          $content .= '<span class="category-subs-parent">' . $box_categories_array[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
        } else {
          $content .= '<span class="category-subs-selected">' . $box_categories_array[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
        }
      } else {
        $content .= $box_categories_array[$i]['name'];
      }

      if ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']) {
        $content .= CATEGORIES_SEPARATOR;
      }

      /* ADDED THIS */
      $content .= '</a>';
      if($i+1 < sizeof($box_categories_array) && $box_categories_array[$i+1]['has_sub_cat'] && $new_style == 'category-top') // new UL
      {
        $content .= '<ul>';
      }
      elseif(($i+1 < sizeof($box_categories_array) && !$box_categories_array[$i+1]['has_sub_cat'] && $new_style == 'category-subs') || $i+1 == sizeof($box_categories_array)) // new UL
      {
        $content .= '</ul></li>';
      }
      else
        $content .= '</li>';
      /* UNTIL HERE */


      if (SHOW_COUNTS == 'true') {
        if ((CATEGORIES_COUNT_ZERO == '1' and $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] == 0) or $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] >= 1) {
          $content .= CATEGORIES_COUNT_PREFIX . $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] . CATEGORIES_COUNT_SUFFIX;
        }
      }

      $content .=  "\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Found a typo. Please try again.

Comment: i am sorry, it only add ul to the first sub category, i want to add the ul to the first sub category, </ul> after the last sub category

Comment: samura,if i want to add the ul label to contain all the subcategory. when the subcategory don't have sub-subsubcategory. <li class="category-top"> <a href="#">...</a>
<ul>
<li class="category-topb"><a href="#">...</a></li>
<li class="category-topb"><a href="#">...</a></li>
<li class="category-topb"><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
how shoud i do.

Comment: you were right. the code was a lie :P Please try this (all new) version. Without testing is a bit more hard.

Comment: i am sorry, the new code doesn't output any ul. now, dont't think about if a subcategory may be contain a sub-subcategory. supposed there are only one level of the category. (main category-->subcategory). i want to add the ul to the subcategory. <li class="category-top"> <a href="#">main category</a> <ul> <li class="category-topb"><a href="#">sub category</a></li> <li class="category-topb"><a href="#">...</a></li> <li class="category-topb"><a href="#">...</a></li> </ul> </li> how do i do?

Comment: Sorry about that yesterday. Too sleepy to think straight. Created an array to test the code and it seems to work.

Comment: i am sorry,i put the code in zencart tpl_categories.php it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you send me a `print_r()` of the `$box_categories_array`?

Comment: In the array you sent there aren't any `category-subs`

Comment: i have same problem please help me @samura

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $content = "";

  $content .= '<div id="' . str_replace('_', '-', $box_id . 'Content') . '" class="sideBoxContent">' . "\n";
  for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($box_categories_array);$i++) {
    switch(true) {
// to make a specific category stand out define a new class in the stylesheet example: A.category-holiday
// uncomment the select below and set the cPath=3 to the cPath= your_categories_id
// many variations of this can be done
//      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['path'] == 'cPath=3'):
//        $new_style = 'category-holiday';
//        break;
      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['top'] == 'true'):
        $new_style = 'category-top';
        break;
      case ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']):
        $new_style = 'category-subs';
        break;
      default:
        $new_style = 'category-products';
      }
     if (zen_get_product_types_to_category($box_categories_array[$i]['path']) == 3 or ($box_categories_array[$i]['top'] != 'true' and SHOW_CATEGORIES_SUBCATEGORIES_ALWAYS != 1)) {
        // skip if this is for the document box (==3)
      } else {
      $content .= '<li class="' . $new_style . '"><a  href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $box_categories_array[$i]['path']) . '">';

      if ($box_categories_array[$i]['current']) {
        if ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']) {
          $content .= '<span class="category-subs-parent">' . $box_categories_array[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
        } else {
          $content .= '<span class="category-subs-selected">' . $box_categories_array[$i]['name'] . '</span>';
        }
      } else {
        $content .= $box_categories_array[$i]['name'];
      }

      if ($box_categories_array[$i]['has_sub_cat']) {
        $content .= CATEGORIES_SEPARATOR;
      }

      $content .= '</a>';
      if($i+1 < sizeof($box_categories_array) && !$box_categories_array[$i+1]['top'] && $box_categories_array[$i]['top']) // new UL
      {
        $content .= '<ul>';
      }
      elseif(($i+1 < sizeof($box_categories_array) && $box_categories_array[$i+1]['top'] && !$box_categories_array[$i]['top']) || $i+1 == sizeof($box_categories_array)) // new UL
      {
        $content .= '</ul></li>';
      }
      else
        $content .= '</li>';


      if (SHOW_COUNTS == 'true') {
        if ((CATEGORIES_COUNT_ZERO == '1' and $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] == 0) or $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] >= 1) {
          $content .= CATEGORIES_COUNT_PREFIX . $box_categories_array[$i]['count'] . CATEGORIES_COUNT_SUFFIX;
        }
      }

      $content .=  "\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I created this new version. Please try.

Comment: thank you, but there is still on ul in the output. i put the screeshot under the following,

Answer (score 0):

There is still no any `ul` in the output.

`echo sizeof($box_categories_array);`  shows `58`

`echo $box_categories_array[2]['top']` shows `false`

[image]

```
print_r($box_categories_array) results:
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=1
            [name] => Hardware
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_17
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CDROM Drives
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_4
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Graphics Cards
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_8
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Keyboards
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_16
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Memory
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_9
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mice
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_6
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monitors
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_5
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Printers
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=1_7
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Speakers
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=2
            [name] => Software
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=2_19
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=2_18
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Simulation
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=2_20
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Strategy
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=3
            [name] => DVD Movies
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_10
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Action
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_13
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cartoons
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_12
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comedy
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_15
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Drama
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_11
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Science Fiction
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=3_14
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Thriller
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=21
            [name] => Gift Certificates
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=22
            [name] => Big Linked
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=23
            [name] => Test Examples
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=24
            [name] => Free Call Stuff
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=33
            [name] => A Top Level Cat
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_34
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubLevel 2 A
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_34_40
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2A1
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_34_43
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2A2
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubLevel 2 B
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35_37
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2B1
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35_38
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2B2
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_35_39
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2B3
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubLevel 2 C
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36_41
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2C1
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36_44
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2C2
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=33_36_42
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub Sub Cat 2C3
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=48
            [name] => Sale Percentage
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_45
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_47
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off Attrib
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_31
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off Skip
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=48_32
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10% off Price
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=49
            [name] => Sale Deduction
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=49_27
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$5.00 off
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=49_52
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$5.00 off Skip
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=50
            [name] => Sale New Price
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=50_46
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Set $100
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=50_51
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Set $100 Skip
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=53
            [name] => Big Unlinked
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=54
            [name] => New v1.2
            [has_sub_cat] => 1
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=54_56
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Attributes
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=54_55
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Discount Qty
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=54_60
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Downloads
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=54_57
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text Pricing
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=54_61
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Real
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [top] => false
            [path] => cPath=54_58
            [name] => &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Real Sale
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=62
            [name] => Music
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=63
            [name] => Documents
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [top] => true
            [path] => cPath=64
            [name] => Mixed Product Types
        )

)
```

Comment: Please open the first `+<li class="category-top">` the <ul> should be inside.